# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre honor y honra?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Hace poco me di cuenta de que existen dos palabras en español que equivalen a la palabra "honor" en inglés: *honor* y *honra*. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estas dos palabras? ¿Cuál es más común?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO, the distinction is very slim (in fact, some times can be exchanged) but...

[Honor](http://rae.es/honor) would be something that dignifies your position in the society for doing something "honorable" not only for you, but for said society itself (a heroic sacrifice in an act of war, for instance) whereas [Honra](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=9Lqg0sgcxDXX2kPNu1hi) would be a bit more personal (you live your own life with virtue)

If you search both terms in the dictionary of the [RAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Academia_Espa%C3%B1ola), the fist two entries for *Honor* mention that is something you get when fulfilling obligations with oneself but also (here's the important part) with your fellow men. On the other hand, the definitions of *Honra* are exclusively related to the individual.

To me, *honor* sounds "bigger" (more important or solemn) than *honra*.

It's a pretty tricky distinction, though.

And about which one is more common... I would say "*honor*" is used more often but that's just (once again) my opinion.

Comment: Also, when used as a verb "to honor someone" in Spanish is "honrar a alguien"

Comment: "honor" is used more often than "honra" and it's not an opinion, have a look at this graph: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=honor%2Chonra&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chonor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chonra%3B%2Cc0